# Crackling/distorted HDMI audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

**EDIT: I realized that every time the audio would be crackling also computer performance overall would be worse, reason was broken GPU.**

So I am running a HDMI cable to my television from my PC where I have Ubuntu 21.04 and I have been battling against an issue for few weeks now where the HDMI audio is crackling and distorted

Everything I have tried so far:

Adding "tsched=0" to back of the line "load-module module-udev-detect"

Adding "options snd-hda-intel vid=8086 pid=8ca0 snoop=0" to alsa-base.conf file

Adding "intel_iommu=igfx_off" to kernel command line

snd_hda_intel_power_save disabled permanently by adding "options snd_hda_intel power_save=0" to the end of /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

Trying different settings in daemon.conf

Deleting speech dispatcher

Reinstalling alsa-base pulseaudio

Muting other outputs in alsamixer that are not in use

Trying different HDMI port

Trying different sound settings on my TV

And those were the tricks I was able to find after several hours of intense googling, none of which unfortunately worked. **Only solution I have found out that if I restart my computer it will start to work, atleast after few restarts.** In related to this it is probably good to mention that doing "sudo killall pulseaudio" does not make any difference.

[Here is alsa-info.txt](https://justpaste.it/4bhlc) Link to justpaste.it because it wouldn't fit here

In the alsa-info there is a line near bottom that says "snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec"
Is this something worth looking at? I tried to google about it but to my (mediocre) understanding this is related to people who run HDMI from back of their motherboard and only have integrated graphics. As I am running the HDMI from back of my 5700XT, that line doesn't concern me, am I right?

Specs: AMD 5700XT, Asus Prime Z590-A, TV is LG 47LM670T-ZA

Answer (score 4):

I am experiencing the same problem. I use `killall speech-dispatcher` when that occurs. It seems that you can remove the speech-dispatcher if you do not use it. It will solve permanently the problem

Comment: Thanks for youe time and answer but like I mentioned i've already deleted it.