# Distorted and Lagged Audio on HDMI/DP sometimes

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

Ubuntu 21.10 (X11)

Nvidia GTX 970 (495 drivers)

Most of the times audio works fine but out of nowhere, I get distorted audio on HDMI and DP.

When I connect my Bluetooth headset, the audio is fine.

Switching outputs, `sudo pulseaudio -k`, logging out/in, unplugging/plugging ports won't solve the problem. An only reboot solves the problem.

Here is a video of the problem:
https://youtu.be/zAAzNl97uLU

Comment: At Nvidia's we can see they suggest 470, not 495.

Comment: Switch to 470. Problem persists.

Comment: Might be this problem: https://askubuntu.com/q/1373352/814284